# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `new_*_path')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`config/routes.rb` has as follows:

```
    resources :<name>, except: [:show, :edit]
```

where `<name>` is a placeholder for the actual name.

And the page `/<name>/new` exists. The variable `<name>_path` is defined, yet when I use the variable `new_<name>_path`, the following error occurs:

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `new_<name>_path')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resources `<name>` should be plural but the helper method for `new` should use the singular version on `<name>`.

Example: `users_path` vs `new_user_path`

Edit: You can use `rake routes` to display all routes available to you.